# DGL: variational problem in $H^1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I've given $f \in L^2(\Omega), g \in H^1(\Omega)$.
I want to find $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ such that $$ -div (A \nabla u ) + <b, \nabla u> + cu = f$$ in $\Omega$
$$u = g$$ on $\Gamma$.

In order to find u, I thought it was a good idea to substitute u by $u=u_0 +g$ and to reformulate the problem as a variational problem for $u_0 \in H^1_0(\Omega)$.

But at the moment, I got stock a bit. Is the "substitution" a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a good idea.

More precisely with $u = u_0+g$ the equation becomes:
$$-\operatorname{div}(A \nabla u_0) +\langle b, \nabla u_0 \rangle+cu_0=\tilde{f}$$
where:
$$\tilde{f}=f+\operatorname{div}(A \nabla g) -\langle b, \nabla g \rangle-c g \in H^{-1}$$

this is then a "classical" variational problem in $H^1_0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just reread my script, but did not find such a "classical" variational problem or a solution to that. If the problem is classical, could you please give me any reference where this type of problem is discussed / solved? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can search for "variational problem and elliptic PDE". For example one of the first result is [this document](https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/ledret/M1English/M1ApproxPDE_Chapter3.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much! May you have also an answer to this question here? ;) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2960454/computation-of-solution-of-minimization-problem

Comment: So, $\tilde{f}=f+\operatorname{div}(A \nabla g) -\langle b, \nabla g \rangle-c g = f + \sum \delta_j (a_{ij}(x) \delta_i u ) - \sum b_i (x) \delta_i u - c(x) u $. Correct? But what is $u$?

Comment: Is the equation above correct?

Comment: By $\delta_i$ do you mean $\partial_i$? And if $u$ is the function you are searching I don't think that the second equality is correct.

Comment: Oh yes, I mean the partials. Hm but what is the correct result of this? I read in your document and found the solution above...

Comment: I think that what you mean is actually : $\tilde{f}=f+\operatorname{div}(A \nabla g) -\langle b, \nabla g \rangle-c g = f + \sum \partial_j (a_{ij}(x) \partial_i {\color{blue} g} ) - \sum b_i (x) \partial_i {\color{blue} g}  - c(x) {\color{blue} g} $ then it is correct :-)